# Is it possible to revert an entire SVN repository?

Tags: svn, undo

I just did something dumb with my SVN repository, I accidentally imported a load of stuff into the root instead of into a subfolder. It will take me ages to clean up.... unless there is an easy way to do a global revert on the repo? The help file talks about reverting working copies but there is no working copy for a newly-imported item. Is there a way to undo an import?

> **Duplicate**: [Roll back or revert entire svn repository to an older
>   revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402159/roll-back-or-revert-entire-svn-repository-to-an-older-revision)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this question: [Roll back or revert entire svn repository to an older revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402159/roll-back-or-revert-entire-svn-repository-to-an-older-revision)

Comment: Good catch, sorry for the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do an backup only up to the desired version and then restore the repository.

```
svnadm dump /path/to/repo -r 0:desired_max
```

should give you the backup you want.

Answer (score 1):

Make a checkout of the complete repository, merge the change out and then commit.

```
$ svn checkout https://server/repro temp
$ cd temp
$ svn merge -c -[revision] https://server/repro
```

Check your working copy is correct

```
$ svn commit -m "Revert of botched import."
```