# Tortoise SVN use previous version as most current version

Tags: tortoisesvn, submit, version

I would like to use a previous version as the most current version using Tortoise SVN. I have a version of the application 4 submissions ago that I would like to use as the current version. I checked it out and I am having trouble submitting it because there are conflicts. Is there anyway to submit a copy forcing it to use the copy being submitted?

Thank you for the help,

Chris

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do "roll back" to a previous "revision". Or, to put this another way, you'd like to undo the 4 latest submissions. If you search StackOverflow for "subversion rollback" or "svn reverse merge" you will probably find helpful answers, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477824/svn-version-rollback-question

Answer (score 1):

It is a very simple task

1. Update you local svn copy
2. Resolve the conflicts as "Accept-Mine"
3. Submit your code.

In terms of Tortoise SVN

1. Update Code (root folder)
2. Select option "Resolve Conflicts using mine"
3. Commit Code.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to set "Accept-Mine" when I commit in TortoiseSvn? Thank you very much for your help.