# Rolling back an svn move/rename

Tags: svn

I absent mindedly mv a folder in my svn trunk instead of branching it. I could just mv it back, but I'm afraid I'd lose history. How is this best undone?

Edit: I should be clear that I did the move on the repository, not my working copy, so it was an automatic commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the subversion manual about [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) in order to *undo* your erroneous changes.

> You can use svn merge to “undo” the
>   change in your working copy, and then
>   commit the local modification to the
>   repository. All you need to do is to
>   specify a reverse difference. (You can
>   do this by specifying --revision
>   303:302, or by an equivalent --change
>   -303.)

```
svn merge -c -303 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to revert so it is as if the move never happened then you need to dump the whole repository up to the revision you want and then recreate the repository.

Check out [here](http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-undo-commit-in-subversion.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402159/roll-back-or-revert-entire-svn-repository-to-an-older-revision) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't commit it:

```
svn revert PATH
```

Comment: 'svn revert' only reverts *local* changes. The SP did the change on the repository.

Comment: @zellus: understood, that's why I said if he didn't commit it.

Answer (score 0):

You better just copy the latest version before the mistaken commit to the same path.

Absently minded move

```
     svn mv -m 'move it!' \
         http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk \
         http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/foo
```

Check the log for the latest version before the move

```
    svn log http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

...

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    r17610 | john.doe | 2017-08-01 11:02:43 -0300 (tue, 01 aug 2017) | 1 line

    move it!
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    r17581 | john.doe | 2017-07-31 17:42:57 -0300 (mon, 31 jul 2017) | 1 line

    fix bug
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Copy the last good version 17581 to HEAD

```
 svn mv -m 'fix absently minded move' \
     http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk@17581 \
     http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

This will fully preserve your history (including the absently minded move)